# mysql timestamp convertion

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, time

What is the correct way to convert from mysql timestamp (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) to my own chosen format, something like "August 5, 2010"? iow how can I make the mysql timestamp php date() compatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways...

First, you can do it in php with [`strtotime()`](http://ie.php.net/strtotime)...

```
$time = strtotime('2010-05-05 05:05:05');
echo date('F j, Y', $time);
```

Or, you can convert it to unix time in MySQL with [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`your timestamp column`) FROM blahblah....
```

You'd then need to format it with `date()` in php after fetching it.

Or, you can do the entire thing right in MySQL with [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`your timestamp column`, '%M %e, %Y') FROM ...
```

Comment: Bad idea to make it with MySQL. You're at the mercy of whatever timezone your database picks, which may or may not be the one PHP is using (let alone that it's more likely it won't have the timezone data set up-to-date).

Comment: @Artefacto Not a bad idea at all.  In fact, it's a VERY good idea.  In fact, I only trust MySQL with dates (because of replication and load balancing).  It can lead to headaches if you mix between PHP and MySQL, but as long as you either pick one and stick with it or test properly you will be fine...

Comment: What? You trust MySQL with dates *because* of replication and load balancing? What do replication and load balancing have to do something like parsing/formatting a date? Mixing PHP and MySQL is a recipe for disaster and trusting MySQL alone is not a whole lot better (does it handle timezones, daylight savings time and rule changes correctly and can have its rules kept up-to-date [throughout the year?](http://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html)).

Comment: We have a geographically replicated master-master setup (1 server in US GMT -5, and 1 server in UK, GMT + 0). MySQL manages the difference in timezone settings between the servers for us.  So if we use `NOW()` here, it'll be the same as if we use `NOW()` there without any input from us (MySQL stores the timezone shift info in the binary logs).  Without that, we'd need to manually correct each date to/from timezones and UTC in PHP (easy for one date, easy to forget for an entire application with many developers)...  We've been doing this for 3 years with no issue.  So yes, I do trust it...

Comment: A timezone shift is as good as nothing, hell it's preferable to store a timestamp instead, at least you won't be tricked by thinking it actually has nay value. I hope you're not storing any future dates in your database (e.g. you're building a calendar application). If you are, make yourself a favor and read the page I've linked to. I also gather that your application only shows the time in the timezone of the server, because otherwise you'd have to do those timezone conversions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can have MySQL return it as an Epoch timestamp which php's date function can handle or use the following function:

`$epoch = strtotime('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');`

[php Manual: strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

Third option: use MySQL's DATE_FORMAT() function (although I prefer ircmaxell's way)

Answer (score 0):

See [`date`](http://php.net/date) and [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime). For manipulations in other time zones, see [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and the [`DateTime`](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.